# How can I hide a CSS modal overlay from screenshots

Tags: php, css

On a site I am working on, there is one of those Modal overlay windows that pops up on user's first visit/if cookie not set. (I know they are annoying but it's necessary)

Now when sites like StumbleUpon.com and Google (site preview for search results), etc take an image of the page, it shows the modal window in the image.  I am not really sure if I can hide this?  The only idea I have is actually checking referrer and hiding it from a list of referrers but this would be hard I would have to try to figure out all the sites that take screenshot images

Is there any other option other then checking and keeping a list of blacklisted referrers?

Comment: You'll have a heck of a job compiling a list of sites.

Comment: the only other thing that comes to my mind would be based on `User-Agent` but it feels more or less like using `Referer`

Comment: What you can do is to make a white list of allowed user agents, presuming that Google, StumbleUpon etc have custom User-Agent names.

Comment: A solution to stop Google from seeing screen shots is checking the user agent header (in php). Look at http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1061943 to see what user agents you should be looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing i could think of, is checking the Useragent Strings serverside.

Here you have a good overview fo the most common UAStrings.

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

Checking the Referer won't be successful, because you can't judge from the referrer if it's a crawler or a normal user.

Be aware however, that UAS can be spoofed. If that is crucial, you might want to consider a DNS-Lookup...

Comment: Be aware that Googlebot will occasionally visit your site with a non-Googlebot UA, and if it finds you're giving a substantially different experience to Googlebot then you're likely to get penalised